# MS Chart Control series label positioning

Tags: c#, label, mschart, series

I've got a gantt chart (RangeBar) I've made with the MS Chart control; for some shorter series, the label gets displayed outside the bar; I'd prefer to set it so the label gets stays inside the bar and gets truncated (with ellipsis would be nice). Is there a way of doing this? I've been poking around in the properties of the chart and series for ages now with no success.

Answer (score 3):

I think the property you need to set is `BarLabelStyle`

eg.

```
chart.Series["mySeries"]["BarLabelStyle"] = "Center";
```

See this [Dundas page](http://support2.dundas.com/OnlineDocumentation/winchart2005/CustomAttributes_BarLabelStyle.html) that explains that custom property which should be similar or same for the MS Chart control.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't change anything for me :|

Comment: I confirm that this does show the label inside the bar - centered, in MSChart.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I rolled my own using this (yes it's messy, it'll get tidied up when I have time):

```
private static void Chart_PostPaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Chart c = ((Chart)sender);
        foreach (Series s in c.Series)
        {
            string sVt = s.GetCustomProperty("PixelPointWidth");
            IGanttable ig = (IGanttable)s.Tag;
            double dblPixelWidth = c.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(s.Points[0].YValues[1]) - c.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(s.Points[0].YValues[0]);

            s.Label = ig.Text.AutoEllipsis(s.Font, Convert.ToInt32(dblPixelWidth)-dblSeriesPaddingGuess);

        }
    }


public static string AutoEllipsis(this String s, Font f, int intPixelWidth)
    {

        if (s.Length == 0 || intPixelWidth == 0) return "";


        var result = Regex.Split(s, "\r\n|\r|\n");

        List<string> l = new List<string>();
        foreach(string str in result)
        {
            int vt = TextRenderer.MeasureText(str, f).Width;
            if (vt < intPixelWidth)
            { l.Add(str); }
            else
            {
                string strTemp = str;
                int i = str.Length;

                while (TextRenderer.MeasureText(strTemp + "…", f).Width > intPixelWidth)
                {
                    strTemp = str.Substring(0, --i);
                    if (i == 0) break;
                }

                l.Add(strTemp + "…");
            }

        }
        return String.Join("\r\n", l);

    }
```

This seems to work quite happily as long as it is the `Post_Paint` event (If you use the `Paint` event it will stop ToolTips from showing)